# Threejs shadow casting noise

Tags: three.js, shadow, noise

When i import a custom mesh and ask it to both cast and receive shadows, a lighting noise appears. Same with a simple mesh, but if there is more than one light source.

Does that come from my computer/browser/code ?

Comment: I have the same issue. This happens to me when an object both casts and receives a shadow.

Comment: Thanks. I also identified a third cause, other light sources. So : 1. Simple meshes seems to handle cast+receive without noise only when there is no other light (even ambient). 2. Indeed, cast+receive creates noise with one light on 'complex' object (to define : 'complex' !). I work on a better example to illustrate it clearly and update this comment.

Comment: Perhaps you should post this as an issue on their github.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment, i was finishing my example when you made me find this [known (how couldnt'it be!) issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5554)

Comment: See how you like it if you set `material.ambient` to the same value as `material.color`. They should normally be identical for a given material, anyway. Do it for the sphere and the plane.

Comment: If you want to respond directly to a user, use @username.

Comment: I learnt a lot on shadows from the links in the github issue. For next readers what i can risk to report is that it seems to be a common problem in 3D world since the beginning, hard to solve in realtime rendering and usually answered with tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Lights in Three.js have a `light.shadow.bias` you can adjust to overcome this exact problem. I think you ou have to use trial-and-error to adjust it. The documentation says to adjust it in steps of 0.0001, but I solved my problem by setting it to minus 1/1,000,000 ( -1e-6 ).
Happy hunting :)

[Three.js documentation on LightShadow](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/lights/shadows/LightShadow)